Android - Recycler View onScrollStateChanged not being called
I have a Main Activity that handles the Fragment Switches in a FrameLayout. The navigation for each of the Fragments are controlled by the BottomNavigationView.
The weird thing is when I go to my Home Fragment which has a RecyclerView and I scroll down to the end, the data loads, but if I start again and got to my Home Fragment and switch to another Fragment and then go back to my Home fragment and scroll to bottom, the onScrollStateChanged never gets called.
I have tried this in onCreateView and still the same thing happens:
Some code in my onCreateView:
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (rootView == null) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.follow_fragment, container, false);
            }
    
            fInterest = new ArrayList<FollowInterest>();
            //just change the fragment_dashboard
            //with the fragment you want to inflate
            //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
            //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
            main = (MainActivity) getContext();
    
            main.iconRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Toast.makeText(((MainActivity) getContext()).getApplication(), "Follow News", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
    
            });
            main.iconSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
    
            });
    
            childOverlay = new View(getActivity());
            
    
            return rootView;
        }

I have this in my onViewCreated:
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    followInterestsList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.followInterestsList);
    followInterestsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    followInterestsList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                //loadFollows(fInterest.get(fInterest.size() - 1).id);
            } else {
                // Scrolling down
                String g = "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                //Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(!hasFinishedResults){
                    if(!isLoading){
                        //fInterest.removeIf(x -> x.isLoadMore == true);
                        loadFollows(fInterest.get(fInterest.size() - 1).id);
                    }

                }else{
                }

            }
        }
    });
    loadFollows(0);

}


I think you're violating fragment lifecycle and not handling transition to/from "detached" state properly but I'm not certain. I'd recommend proper implementation of view destruction and recreation rather than "caching" it in "rootView" variable and see if it fixes the issue.

You don't save rootView of a fragment. remove if (rootView == null) from onCreateView .

Spirit that did the trick
